# GPutil not working properly on NVIDIA Jetson Xavier NX

Tags: python, gpu, nvidia-jetson, jetson-xavier

I've written code that collects telemetry information from the device and saves it in a `.csv` file.

However, I'm not able to detect the **GPU** from the `GPUtil`:

```
import GPUtil

GPU = GPUtil.getAvailable()

print(GPU)
print(GPUtil.__version__)
```

**Output:**

```
[]
1.4.0
```

I didn't find information if it has any relation with the type of architecture of Jetson.

Below is some additional system information:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of hard work to come up with some solution, I came to some conclusions that I share here.

Reading a little more about `GPUtil` and analyzing the `GPUtil` source code [here](https://github.com/anderskm/gputil/blob/master/GPUtil/GPUtil.py) it becomes clear that:

> GPUtil is a Python module for getting the GPU status from NVIDA GPUs using nvidia-smi.

Unfortunately, `nvidia-smi` does not work on **NVIDIA Jetson** devices (Xavier NX, Nano, AGX Xavier, TX1, TX2).

As my goal was to fetch telemetry data, there were two options:

- `tegrastats`;
- `jetson-stats`.

I found `tegrastats` options quite limited as `tegrastats` reports memory and processor usage for **Tegra** based devices, but it would be necessary to create a **bash** file, for, for example, automate the process.

You can find the `tegrastats` utility [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/drive/drive_os_5.1.6.1L/nvvib_docs/index.html#page/DRIVE_OS_Linux_SDK_Development_Guide/Utilities/util_tegrastats.html).

As my goal was to create a **Python script** to fetch telemetry data together with other libraries, like `cputil`, the solution adopted was use the `jtop` from `jetson-stats` as a **Python library**.

> jetson-stats is a package for monitoring and control your NVIDIA Jetson [Xavier NX, Nano, AGX Xavier, TX1, TX2] and works with all NVIDIA Jetson ecosystem.
>
> jtop is a system monitoring utility that runs on the terminal and see and control realtime the status of your NVIDIA Jetson. CPU, RAM, GPU status and frequency and other.

To use it, was needed to **install** `jetson-stats`:

`$ sudo -H pip install -U jetson-stats`

To use `jtop` just type in the **terminal** the command `jtop`. The prompt interface will be show.

To import `jtop` as a **Python library** just write the following line of code in **Python script**:

`from jtop import jtop`

And in my specific case I used the following **snippet code**:

```
with jtop() as jetson:
    xavier_nx = jetson.stats

    CPU_temperature = xavier_nx['Temp CPU']
    GPU_temperature = xavier_nx['Temp GPU']
    Thermal_temperature = xavier_nx['Temp thermal']
```

`.stats` returns a python `dict` structure, and the available data values are:

> time, uptime, jetson_clocks, nvp model, CPU1, CPU2, CPU3, CPU4, CPU5,
> CPU6, GPU, MTS FG, MTS BG, RAM, EMC, SWAP, APE, NVENC, NVDEC, NVJPG,
> fan, Temp AO, Temp AUX, Temp CPU, Temp GPU, Temp thermal, power cur,
> power avg.

Unfortunately `jetson-stats` doesn't work with `Docker`. This can be a negative and important point when thinking about using this service in your application.

Answer (score 0):

jetson-stats also works in Docker.
Following the documentation: https://rnext.it/jetson_stats/docker.html

1. Install jetson-stats on your host
2. Install jetson-stats on your container as well
3. Pass to your container `/run/jtop.sock:/run/jtop.sock`

example of Docker

```
docker run --rm -it -v /run/jtop.sock:/run/jtop.sock rbonghi/jetson_stats:latest
```

I hope I have helped you